# What does this quotient group $\frac{C^*}{R^+}$ represent?

Tags: group-theory

If $C^*$ and $R^+$ denote the multiplicative group of non zero complex numbers and the subgroup of positive reals, then what does the quotient group $\frac{C^*}{R^+}$ mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you remember your basic group theory, you will recall that the elements of the group $C^\ast/R^+$ are the *cosets* of $R^+$ in $C^\ast$; furthermore, $z_1, z_2 \in C^\ast$ are in the same coset if and only if $z_1 z_2^{-1} \in R^+$, i.e., if and only if $z_1 = rz_2$ for 
some $r \in R^+$.  This means that $z_1$ and $z_2$ lie on the same ray through the origin, so we must have $\arg z_1 = \arg z_2$.  And it's beginning to look a lot like $C^\ast/R^+$ is the circle group $S^1$ . . .

Indeed, writing $z_j = r_j e^{i\theta_j}$, $j = 1, 2$, we see from $z_1 = rz_2$ or $r_1  e^{i\theta_1} = rr_2e^{i\theta_2}$ that $r_1 = r r_2$ and $e^{i\theta_1} = e^{i\theta_2}$; restricting $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in [0, 2\pi)$ we have $\theta_1 = \theta_2$; each coset is thus represented by a unique $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ or, equivalently, a unique unimodular complex number $e^{i\theta}$.  Furthermore, it is easy to see that since $z_1 z_2 = r_1 r_2 e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}$, the natural projection $C^\ast \to C^\ast/R^+ = S^1$ is a homomorphism taking $z_1z_2$ to $\theta_1 + \theta_2$, where we use the usual addition $\mod 2\pi$.  $C^\ast/R^+$ is the circle group indeed.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: And you are more than welcome!