# Real numbers modulo $1$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In teaching material of my professor I read "where $x_1,x_2,...,x_m$ are distinct real numbers modulo $1$". What is the definition of numbers modulo $1$? Intuitively I would say that there exist a number c such that
$$x_n=c\ n \ \ \forall n \in\mathbb N$$
is it right?

Comment: This is the circle group $\, \Bbb R/\Bbb Z,\,$ e.g. see [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/68432/242) and [here too.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/929456/242)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite. Usually $x$ and $y$ are said to be distinct real numbers modulo $1$ if $x-y$ is not an integer. The intuition being that numbers are congruent modulo $n$ if their difference is an integer multiple of $n$.

Comment: thank you; $x-y$ should not be integer, or it should not be integer less than $1$?

Comment: @Lely Just should not be an integer. The relation is symmetric.